# How to process different long tasks with sweave R?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am using Rstudio and sweave to build a report.
Everything is working well but I have to do a lot of different heavy computation. 
They take different  hours each one.

My file now look like this :

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amscd}
    \usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}
    \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

    \title{OES dataset}
    \author{Luca Puggini}

    \maketitle

    \section{The dataset}
   This is my data:
<<echo=T>>=
#suppose this  is a very heavy task that takes a lot of time
x=matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
y=rnorm(10)
@
\section{operation}
Now let's do some operations 
<<echo=T>>=
x=x+1
y=y+10
@

\end{documents}
```

Now I change the last line for example

```
y=y+10000 # instead of y=y+10
```

How can I compile the pdf without recomputing all the tasks (but only the last one)?

EDIT:
Probably the best thing to do is to switch to knitr and use the cache. 
Can someone please write the code of how solve this problem with cache?

Comment: You can implement a simple cache system - if some result exist (plot image, text output, etc) use it, otherwise run the computation and save the result. Create some name convention to save the results in a clever way.

Comment: if you switch to `knitr` (probably a good idea) there is a built-in caching system (google "knitr cache")

Comment: People still use sweave?

Comment: @TylerRinker: You bet, and what's this immature knitr thing anyway?

Comment: I will probably move to knitr. If there is something better just let me know.  Can you please write how to solve my original problem using knitr?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Task View for Reproducible Research](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html) which covers a number of caching solution.

Caching solutions are also simple to do yourself in a chunk:

```
 if (!exists(someVar)) {
     if (file.exists("cache/someVar.rds")) {
         someVar <- readRDS("cache/someVar.rds")
     } else {
         someVar <- reallyExpensiveComputation()
         saveRDS(someVar, "cache/someVar.rds")
     }
 }
```

[knitr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=knitr) also offers it from the start.